# fork() and execvp()

Tags: c, fork, execvp

I'm having problems trying to execute a process using `fork()` and `execvp()`. I have a struct `Pcb` which has an array of arguments (`args`):

```
#define MAXARGS 2

struct pcb {
    pid_t pid;             // system process ID
    char *args[MAXARGS];  // program name and args
    int arrivaltime;
    int remainingcputime;
    struct pcb * next;     // links for Pcb handlers
    int priority, memalloc, res1, res2, res3, res4, status;
};
typedef struct pcb Pcb;
typedef Pcb * PcbPtr;
```

the first of which is the name of the program to be executed.

And this is my fork function

```
PcbPtr startPcb(PcbPtr process) {
    int pid;
    switch (pid=fork()) {
        case -1:
            return NULL;
        case 0:
            execvp(process->args[0], process->args);
        default:
            return process;
    }
    process->status = 2;
    return process;
}
```

*Note: `process->args[0]` is just a const string called "process" which refers to a compiled program called 'process' in the current directory.*
There  are no arguments.

When I use gdb and follow the child process its just says:

```
[New process 15186]
[Switching to process 15186]
13                              execvp(process->args[0], process->args);
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
startPcb (process=0x602250) at util.c:13
13                              execvp(process->args[0], process->args);
(gdb)
```

Why is it receiving SIGSTP?

Comment: Does this occur if you're _not_ tracing in gdb?

Comment: yes: "[24]+  Stopped                 ./hostd feed"

Comment: Try running `strace -ff -o trace ./yourprogram`, and pastebin the `trace.NNNNN` files it'll create. This will list all the syscalls your program is doing - at a lower level than gdb will show you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Ive pasted them into one page: http://pastebin.com/NzYUVUvQ

Comment: You should put some error handling code after the `execvp()` in case the shell can't execute the program.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wasn't specifying the full path in args[0]

Comment: There'd be not much point in using `execvp()` if the `args[0]` value contains a path (anything with a slash `/` in it).  Then the PATH can't be used to find it.